# Invalid Identifier in Hibernate Filter defaultCondition when trying to access a field of one of it's subfields

Tags: java, hibernate

I am working on setting up some entities for a project that I am working on. My issue is that I am getting an invalid identifier error on my hibernate filters. Below is a simplified example:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "###")
public class C1 {
    
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "###")
   @Filter(name = "C2.set1Filter")
   private Set<C2> set1;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "###")
   @Filter(name = "C2.set2Filter")
   private Set<C2> set2;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "###")
   @Filter(name = "C2.set3Filter")
   private Set<C2> set3;
    
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "###")
@FilterDefs({
   @FilterDef(
      name = "set1Filter"
      defaultCondition = "c3.value = 'One'"
   ),
   @FilterDef(
       name = "set2Filter"
       defaultCondition = "c3.value = 'Two'"
   ),
   @FilterDef(
       name = "set3Filter"
       defaultCondition = "c3.value = 'Three'"
   )
})
public class C2 {

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "ID")
   C3 c3;
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "###")
public class C3 {
   
   @Id
   @Column(name = "ID")
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "VALUE")
   private String value;
}
```

When the filters are off, they don't run, and therefore I don't get an error. However, when they are on, I am getting an error saying that `c3.value` is an invalid identifier.

I am obviously doing something wrong here. Is it possible to get the above to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it stated in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-filter):

> The `@Filter` condition uses a SQL condition and not a JPQL filtering predicate.

So, you should use actual tables and columns names.

```java
@Filter(
    name="setFilter",
    condition="{c3}.VALUE = :val",
    aliases = {
        @SqlFragmentAlias( alias = "c3", table= "C3_TABLE_NAME")
    }
)
```

As it stated [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-filter-sql-fragment-alias):

> When using the `@Filter` annotation and working with entities that are mapped onto multiple database tables, you will need to use the `@SqlFragmentAlias` annotation if the `@Filter` defines a condition that uses predicates across multiple tables.